# JQuery validation "remote" method response waiting message

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I am using JQuery validation plugin "remote" method for Ajax based validation.

But I have to make some third party calls to verify data and it takes approx. 30 seconds.

So need to show some message to end user while data is getting processed by Ajax request. Can anyone help to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see an example from below that i done:

jQuery Validate (Remote Method):

```
$("#myform").validate({
    rules: {
        email: {
            required: true,
            email: true,
            remote: {
                url: 'your-url-or-path-here.php',
                cache: false,
                dataType: 'POST', // Post, Get, Json, etc
                data: {
                    field: $('.element').val()
                }
                beforeSend: function () {
                    $('.loading').css('display','none').show();
                },
                complete: function () {
                    $('.loading').hide();
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: In that case please see my updated answer, remote is a full aJax request, so the above should work as normal

Comment: This is true.   As per documentation, `remote` method will accept all the same options as jQuery `.ajax()`.