# Bootstrap: show some message while remote validation is processing

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, validation

I have a pretty stupid question; however, I am new to this language and learning bootstrap of my own. I have actually searched almost for 3 days now and could not find a solution. I have followed the method mentioned in here http://formvalidation.io/examples/getting-notified-field-being-validated/ but still not able to solve. Basically I want to show something like "Processing..." while the remote validation is in execution but for some reason I am not able to do that. Dear Site Admin, sorry if this is a duplicate question; however, I have even followed the solution provided here [JQuery validation "remote" method response waiting message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31286795/jquery-validation-remote-method-response-waiting-message) but could not get my head around with it... :(

My Code...

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#registerform").bootstrapValidator({
    //live: 'enabled',
    onkeyup: false,
    feedbackIcons: {
        valid: 'fa fa-thumbs-o-up',
        invalid: 'fa fa-remove',
        validating: 'fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin'
    },

    // Specify the validation rules
    fields: {
        name: {
            validators: {
                stringLength: {
                    min: 6,
                },
                notEmpty: {
                    message: 'You are required to fill your full name'
                }
            }
        },
        username: {
            threshold: 6,
            validators: {
                stringLength: {
                    min: 6,
                },
                notEmpty: {
                    message: 'You are required to fill a username of your choice'
                },
                regexp: {
                    regexp: /^[a-zA-Z0-9_\.]+$/,
                    message: 'The username can only consist of alphabetical, number, dot and underscore'
                },
                remote: {
                    url: '/remote.php',
                    type: 'POST',
                    message: 'Oops! That username is already taken',
                    delay: 2000
                },
            }
        },
        email: {
            validators: {
                notEmpty: {
                    message: 'Please supply your email address'
                },
                emailAddress: {
                    message: 'Please supply a valid email address'
                }
            }
        },
        password: {
            validators: {
                stringLength: {
                    min: 8,
                },
                notEmpty: {
                    message: 'Please set a password'
                },
                regex: /^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#\$%\^&\*])(?=.{8,})/, /* Minimum eight characters, at least one letter, one number and one special character: */
                callback: {
                    callback: function(value, validator, $field) {
                        var password = $field.val();
                        if (password == '') {
                            return true;
                        }

                        var result  = zxcvbn(password),
                        score   = result.score,
                        message = result.feedback.warning || 'The password is weak';

                        // Update the progress bar width and add alert class
                        var $bar = $('#strengthBar');
                        switch (score) {
                            case 0:
                                $bar.attr('class', 'progress-bar progress-bar-danger').css('width', '1%');
                                break;
                            case 1:
                                $bar.attr('class', 'progress-bar progress-bar-danger').css('width', '25%');
                                break;
                            case 2:
                                $bar.attr('class', 'progress-bar progress-bar-danger').css('width', '50%');
                                break;
                            case 3:
                                $bar.attr('class', 'progress-bar progress-bar-warning').css('width', '75%');
                                break;
                            case 4:
                                $bar.attr('class', 'progress-bar progress-bar-success').css('width', '100%');
                                break;
                        }

                        // We will treat the password as an invalid one if the score is less than 3
                        if (score < 3) {
                            return {
                                valid: false,
                                message: message
                            }
                        }
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        passwordConfirm: { 
            validators: {
                notEmpty: {
                    message: 'Please set a password'
                },
                identical: {
                    field: 'password',
                    message: 'Passwords do not match'
                },
                different: {
                    field: 'username',
                    message: 'The password cannot be the same as username'
                }
            }
        },

.on('status.field.bv', function(e, data) {
    // Change username to your field name
    if (data.field === 'username' && data.validator === 'remote') {
        (data.status === 'VALIDATING')? $('#processing').show(): $('#processing').hide();
    }
});
```

});

And the other thing is while the username field validation is in execution where the icon changes to spinning circle; however, as soon as someone start typing in the Confirm Password, the validating icon changes to cross bar. This is possibly due to 'different' check been put in place. Is there a way to prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best you can use this bootstrap to show a message is [bootbox](http://bootboxjs.com/)

You can use something like

```
var dialog = bootbox.dialog({
    title: 'working',
    message: '<p><i class="fa fa-spin fa-spinner"></i> Loading...</p>'
});
dialog.init(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        dialog.find('.bootbox-body').html('All work is done!');
    }, 3000);
});
```

And you can prevent the change of the input password by setting it as only read.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank Braian for the response. Could you also guide me where should I add this piece of code? I am pretty sure that I am doing something wrong.

Comment: I don’t understand where you want to use it

Comment: My bad, I missed mentioning the specific point...basically, while the username availability is being checked (i.e., VALIDATING state) using 'remote' method, I would like to show this message

Comment: Hey Braian, does my comment make sense? :S

Comment: sorry never use that plugin before but I think you need to use it inside .on('status.field.fv', function() {})

Comment: did you find the solution? fell free to edit my answer

Comment: Yes, I did, it's a kind of hack though and not the correct method.... have added onStatus function....       onStatus: function(e, data) {
     if (data.status === 'VALIDATING') {
      $("#processing").show();
      $("#uname").attr('readonly', 'readonly');
     }
     else {
      $("#uname").removeAttr('readonly');
      $("#processing").hide();
     }
    },

Comment: Glad, add it to the answer so we make can use it later. Best!